# jQuery getJSON parsing an array of dicts and flling a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code in my page:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var $table = $('#search_body');
    $.getJSON("/search_issues/" + $("#folders").val(), function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, dict) {
            alert ('each index ' + index);
            $.each(obj, function(key, value){
                alert('each key ' + key + ':' + value);
                $table.innerHTML="<tr><td>" + key + ':' + value + "</td></tr>";
            });
        });
    });
});
```

In the HTML markup, I have a table defined and the body of the table is defined as

```
<tbody id="search_body">
</tbody>
```

I put the two alert statements in the code, and it turns out, the first alert only pops up once, telling me index is 0.

If however, I point my browser to the url that is generated for the call to getJSON, I get an array of 9 objects.

This leads me to believe that my syntax in the inner (or possibly the outer) loop is incorrect. So, I went to an online lint form, and it said that I had no syntax errors, so it looks like a logic error.

BTW, $('#folders') does have a valid value (it's a dropdown and it has been selected)

Thanks

The objects returned when I point my browser is this:

```
[
    {
        planning: 0,
        id: "0e1a9dba-8bfe-4316-8923-b76f76da3171",
        rank: 0,
        title: "Test Issue 4"
    },
    {
        planning: 0,
        id: "16ef48ab-1257-4fe4-a4ea-bb2a4b2757f6",
        rank: 0,
        title: "Test Issue 3"
    },
    {
        planning: 0,
        id: "4086f816-57dd-49e7-91a4-ef2ac9573555",
        rank: 0,
        title: "Test Issue 1"
    },
    {
        planning: 0,
        id: "45c598f0-fd6a-48d6-9822-1ca8b0a5af4b",
        rank: 0,
        title: "Test Issue 2"
    },
    {
        planning: 0,
        id: "50a62544-3350-4c78-a9eb-9d79a37846ea",
        rank: 0,
        title: "Test Issue 4"
    },
    {
        planning: 0,
        id: "ae7fa839-1161-4d54-92da-662e6aa35936",
        rank: 0,
        title: "Test Issue 6"
    },
    {
        planning: 0,
        id: "c4016338-a766-46ba-a651-3879a844f141",
        rank: 0,
        title: "Test creating an issue"
    },
    {
        planning: 0,
        id: "d9f38b4f-d4ef-4abf-ab30-d511c0082df1",
        rank: 0,
        title: "Test Issue 5"
    }
```

]

Comment: Why don't you post the nine objects as well, or more specifically the entire content the URL is giving you

Comment: Post the content of data as well, not enough info to be of any help

Comment: If submit is a submit button, you need to cancel the click action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am changing your code a little bit assuming that this is the desired output:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var $table = $('#search_body');
    $.getJSON("/search_issues/" + $("#folders").val(), function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, dict) {
            var $tr = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo($table);
            $.each(dict, function(key, value){
                $tr.append("<td>" + key + ': ' + value + "</td>");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`obj` does not appear defined ? Try substituting

```
$.each(dict, function(key, value){
```

for

```
$.each(obj, function(key, value){
```

---

Also substituting

```
$table[0].innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + key + ':' + value + "</td></tr>";
```

for

```
$table.innerHTML="<tr><td>" + key + ':' + value + "</td></tr>";
```

to concatenate `innerHTML` of `$table`; `$table[0]` being `DOM` element having property `.innerHTML` ; `$table` being jQuery object not having method `.innerHTML`

---

```js
var data = [
    {
        planning: 0,
        id: "0e1a9dba-8bfe-4316-8923-b76f76da3171",
        rank: 0,
        title: "Test Issue 4"
    },
    {
        planning: 0,
        id: "16ef48ab-1257-4fe4-a4ea-bb2a4b2757f6",
        rank: 0,
        title: "Test Issue 3"
    },
    {
        planning: 0,
        id: "4086f816-57dd-49e7-91a4-ef2ac9573555",
        rank: 0,
        title: "Test Issue 1"
    },
    {
        planning: 0,
        id: "45c598f0-fd6a-48d6-9822-1ca8b0a5af4b",
        rank: 0,
        title: "Test Issue 2"
    },
    {
        planning: 0,
        id: "50a62544-3350-4c78-a9eb-9d79a37846ea",
        rank: 0,
        title: "Test Issue 4"
    },
    {
        planning: 0,
        id: "ae7fa839-1161-4d54-92da-662e6aa35936",
        rank: 0,
        title: "Test Issue 6"
    },
    {
        planning: 0,
        id: "c4016338-a766-46ba-a651-3879a844f141",
        rank: 0,
        title: "Test creating an issue"
    },
    {
        planning: 0,
        id: "d9f38b4f-d4ef-4abf-ab30-d511c0082df1",
        rank: 0,
        title: "Test Issue 5"
    }
];

    var $table = $('#search_body');
//    $.getJSON("/search_issues/" + $("#folders").val(), function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, dict) {
            alert ('each index ' + index);
            $.each(dict, function(key, value){
                alert('each key ' + key + ':' + value);
                $table[0].innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + key + ':' + value + "</td></tr>";
            });
        });
//    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody id="search_body">
</tbody>
  </table>
```